# Consulta a Tabla de Gran tamano Demora mucho

Tags: sql, mariadb

Tengo una base de datos donde una de sus tablas esta creciendo demasiado, en un principio crei que era algun fallo que cometi en mi codig lo que hacia **demorara** mucho en responder a la consulta, pero despues de verificar a detalle conclui que el problema no era el codigo sino el **peso de la tabla**.

De todas las tablas de mi base, solo cuando hago una consulta a esa **tabla pesada** es cuando se demora en responder de 6 hasta 8 segundos :(
Pero cuando consulto a cualquiera de las otras tablas se demora casi menos de 1 segundo.

La consulta que estoy realizando es la siguiente:

```
select * from IMPORTACIONES where ID_USUARIO='Hash_Id' order by FECHA DESC limit 1,12;
```

Que en este caso estoy seleccionando solo los primeros 12 registros de la tabla IMPORTACIONES, ordenados por fecha descendiente y tomando como campo base **ID_USUARIO**, que en este caso el ID_USUARIO es "un codigo unico" que se le asigna a la cuenta del usuario para identificar sus movimientos en la tabla. Y ya en la pagina realizo la paginacion usando el flujo GET pasando la variable "?page=NUMERO_PAGINA".

El mismo **select** ya mencionado lo uso para listar otras tablas, y se efectua la consulta en casi menos de 1 segundo, solo demora cuando consulto la tabla de **IMPORTACIONES**.

Les comparto imagen de la tabla que me esta demorando **marcada con rojo**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¿Cuántas columnas tiene esa tabla? Si son muchas y no te hacen falta todas para tu informe, pon solo las columnas necesarias.

¿Están indexados los campos sobre los que buscas (ID_USUARIO, FECHA)? Si tienes muchas consultas en la que entran en juego condiciones sobre esos 2 campos a la vez, puedes probar a crear un nuevo indice sobre dichos campos.

Comment: Muy de acuerdo con los dos comentarios que te ha dicho Ryu. Intenta siempre evitar el famoso "SELECT *", porque igual tu query no precisa todas las columnas de la tabla. En segundo lugar, intenta crear un índice CLUSTERED para ID_USUARIO y FECHA. Respecto a limit, si lo puedes controlar en servidor, es mejor que hacerlo en SQL. Los OFFSET, LIMIT, y TOP son instrucciones que se realizan tras el SELECT, los JOIN , los WHERE y los ORDER (aparte de los GROUP, HAVING,..., si los hubiera). Si te puedes ahorrar el ejecutarlo, mejor que mejor.

Comment: De hecho no uso JOIN ni GROUp ni HAVING, ya que dispongo de la variable "ID_USUARIO" para todas mis tablas y tratar de hacer directo consultar SELECT. 

Tomare el consejo de no usar "*" ya que solo requiero ciertos valores para mostrar en los casos del tipo "Lista de elementos".

Hare la prueba con una consulta en especial, en produccion...

Comment: He quitado el select * y colocado especificamente los unicos valores que uso en el historial visual, pero aun asi sigue tardando igual, vaya, no hace ninguna diferiencia :(

Sobre el numero de columnas de la tabla gorda que me da problemas, tiene 84 columnas.

Answer (score 0):

La tabla no parece tener muchos registros, pero si tener un peso importante.
Como te han indicado, para acelerar la búsqueda puedes crear un index sobre las columnas que realizan la partición.
También quita ese asterisco por los nombres nominales de las columnas, ya que el optimizador de consultas, puede obviar que tengas indices en la tabla, por el mero hecho de tener un asterisco, con lo cual, puede realizar un scan completo de la clave primaria, para ir a buscar por cada una de las entradas sus valores, de las columnas, sin aprovechar ninguno de los índices que pueda disponer la tabla.

```
Explain Select * from IMPORTACIONES where ID_USUARIO='Hash_Id' order by FECHA DESC limit 1,12;
```

Comment: He eliminado el * de todas mis consultas y dejado algo asi: "select Campo,Campo,NCampo.... ", pero sigo presentanto lentitud al consultar esa tabla gorda.

Lo que me falta es agregar un indice, quedo pendiente de confirmar eso.

Comment: Crea el index sobre las columnas que discriminan el where. En este caso id_usuario y fecha, y debes de observar una mejora brutal.